# Trouble configuring NextAuth and tRPC's Websockets when deploying

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, next.js, next-auth

I have built an app with tRPCv10 and NextAuth. As my app requires realtime updates, I have followed tRPC's docs on implementing subscriptions with websockets. [tRPC docs on subscription](https://trpc.io/docs/subscriptions) [tRPC example app](https://github.com/trpc/examples-next-prisma-websockets-starter).

From what I understand, to use websockets in tRPC, I need to create a standalone http server and run it alongside my Nextjs app. When I emit data through EventEmitter, the data is proxied through this http server and sent to all other subscribers. Thus, I have deployed my standalone http server on Railway with port 6957, and my Nextjs app on Vercel

Everything is working well when I am developing, through localhost. However, when I'm trying to deploy it, there is an error trying to connect to the websocket server and I'm receiving a NextAuth error when logging in too.

For example, my server name is "https://xxx-server.up.railway.app/" and my Nextjs app is "https://xxx-client.vercel.app/".

On the client side, I'm receiving an error: WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx-server.up.railway.app:6957/' failed. When I hit the login button which runs the authorize function in NextAuth, the console returns the error: POST https://xxx-client.vercel.app/api/auth/calback/credentials? 401.

For reference, here are the file for _app.tsx and my websocket server:

```
// _app.tsx
const MyApp: AppType = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) => {
  return (
    
      <SessionProvider session={session} refetchOnWindowFocus={false}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </SessionProvider>
  );
};

const getBaseUrl = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return "";
  }
  if (process.env.VERCEL_URL) return `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`; // SSR should use vercel url

  return `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT ?? 3000}`; // dev SSR should use localhost
};

function getEndingLink() {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return httpBatchLink({
      url: `${getBaseUrl()}/api/trpc`,
    });
  }

  const client = createWSClient({
    url: "wss://xxx-server.up.railway.app:6957"
  });

  return wsLink<AppRouter>({
    client,
  });
}

export default withTRPC<AppRouter>({
  config({ ctx }) {
    /**
     * If you want to use SSR, you need to use the server's full URL
     * @link https://trpc.io/docs/ssr
     */
    const url = `${getBaseUrl()}/api/trpc`;

    return {
      url,
      transformer: superjson,
      links: [getEndingLink()],

      /**
       * @link https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient
       */
      // queryClientConfig: { defaultOptions: { queries: { staleTime: 60 } } },
    };
  },
  /**
   * @link https://trpc.io/docs/ssr
   */
  ssr: true,
})(MyApp);
```

```
// prodServer.ts
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || "3000", 10);
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const proto = req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"];
    if (proto && proto === "http") {
      // redirect to ssl
      res.writeHead(303, {
        location: `https://` + req.headers.host + (req.headers.url ?? ""),
      });
      res.end();
      return;
    }
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url!, true);
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  });
  const wss = new ws.Server({ server });
  const handler = applyWSSHandler({ wss, router: appRouter, createContext });

  process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
    console.log("SIGTERM");
    handler.broadcastReconnectNotification();
  });
  server.listen(port);

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
  console.log(
    `> Server listening at http://localhost:${port} as ${
      dev ? "development" : process.env.NODE_ENV
    }`
  );
});
```